# How to use Calendar.Events.patch in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have searched and searched trying to find the answer to this but from all the examples and answers I've read I can't see what my problem is.

I am trying to update the extended properties of a series of events selected by a user.  The IDs of the calendar events (from the Advanced API, not the built in CalendarApp) are stored in an array as they're selected.  I'm then passing this array to a function to be looped through and update the extended properties of each event identified in the array.

It simply doesn't work, I just get `null` returned from the `patch` call, not even an error that I could work with.  Here is a [screenshot of logged output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJF4w.png), the `null` at the end if what the `patch` request returns.

My function is:

```
function updateLessonsStatus(arrCalIds){
  try {
    Logger.log(arrCalIds);
    arrCalIds.forEach(function(row){
      Logger.log(row);
      var objEventPatch = {
        "resource": {
          "extendedProperties": {
            "shared": {
              "status": "accounted"
            }
          }
        }
      };
      Logger.log(objEventPatch);
      return Calendar.Events.patch(objEventPatch, "primary", row);
      //return true;
    });
  }

  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

I have also tried setting `objEventPatch` like this as per Google's Calendar API patch 'Try this API' reference https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch :

```
      var objEventPatch = {
        "calendarId": "primary",
        "eventId": row,
        "resource": {
          "extendedProperties": {
            "shared": {
              "status": "accounted"
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

I still get null from Google Apps Script.  I can succesfully `get` and `patch` events using the IDs I have using the 'Try this API' feature.

There are very few examples of using the advanced APIs with Google Apps Script in Google's documentation and nothing I could find for `patch` so I have used the Javascript examples to construct what I have written so far.

Can anybody help with what I am doing wrong?

(UPDATED for clarity and included image of `null` returned logger output)

Comment: So, if you perform your request from the UI with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) feature - you get `null`? What do you mean by `null`? The `try this API` feature always retuns some kind of response. Are you sure your event ids are correct and you are the owner of those events? You can doublecheck with [Events:get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get).

Comment: @ziganotschka sorry I should have made that clearer.  I'm getting `null` in the script logs when I log out the response from Google Apps Script. The `try this API` feature does work and I have manually updated a calendar event using it, but when taking that code into GAS (without the authentication part because it's built in to GAS) the IDs I pass are not getting updated.  ID's are pulled from my own calendar in a different function.

Comment: What does the resut of `Logger.log(arrCalIds);` and `Logger.log(row);` look like?

Comment: @ziganotschka I have now included a link to a screenshot of the logged output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are providing one nested object too much

Modify

```
      var objEventPatch = {
        "resource": {
          "extendedProperties": {
            "shared": {
              "status": "accounteddd"
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

to

```js
      var objEventPatch = {
          "extendedProperties": {
            "shared": {
              "status": "accounteddd"
            }
          }
        };
```

Side note:

If you want to explore the request response for troubleshooting purposes, I recommend you to perform your request with a call to the request URL with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) instead of using the prebuilt `Calendar` service.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you.  The patch still returned `null` however, which makes it difficult to check if it worked since it didn't throw an error when it wasn't.  The only way I know it worked was to use the same event ID on the `get` Try this API page.  WIll `patch` in apps script not return anything?

Comment: Did you try with UrlfetchApp?

Comment: No, that was with my existing script.  I'm not familair with using the UrlFetchApp so will need to read up on how to use that and the authentication/authorisation process.

Comment: So it turns out the `patch` request does return an event object but that's not getting returned out of the function.  I've marked this as answered because you've solved my original problem, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727638/how-to-insert-file-to-a-shared-drive-using-rest-on-apps-script/61776451#61776451) to create file with URL fetch. You can do the same for patching an event if you modify the request URL and the request body accordingly with the [parameters](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) for this method. Then you can log the response or response code.