# Google drive archiving script with shared drives

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

- I have a script that automatically archives files if the filenames match, it looks for prefixes like 'ARCHIVE_BOM' and will then move that to its respective archive folder. I have gotten this to work on my personal drive but it won't work on shared drives:

  ```
  function moveFiles() {
    var dfldrs=['ARCHIVE_DRW','ARCHIVE_BOM','ARCHIVE_STP'];//Three letter prefixes
    var ofObj={ARCHIVE_DRW:'id',ARCHIVE_BOM:'id',ARCHIVE_STP:'id'};//distribution folder ids
    var upldFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('id');
    var files=upldFldr.getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      var file=files.next();
      var key=file.getName().slice(0,11);
      var index=dfldrs.indexOf(key);
      if(index>-1) {
        Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": ofObj[key]}]}, file.getId());  
      }
      }
    }
  ```
- I know that I need to add {supportsTeamDrives: true} somewhere but can't get it to work properly, if someone could help me place this it would be great.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776451/7215091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in the current stage when the ID instead of the filename is used, `DriveApp.getFolderById('id')` can be used for the shared Drive. So, in this case, how about modifying `Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": ofObj[key]}]}, file.getId());` as follows?

#### From:

```
Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": ofObj[key]}]}, file.getId());
```

#### To:

```
Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": ofObj[key] }] }, file.getId(), null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
```

or

```
Drive.Files.patch({ "parents": [{ "id": ofObj[key] }] }, file.getId(), { supportsAllDrives: true });
```

- In the case of `Drive.Files.update`, please put `{ supportsAllDrives: true }` to the 4th argument.
- In the case of `Drive.Files.patch`, please put `{ supportsAllDrives: true }` to the 3rd argument.
- If in your situation, `DriveApp.getFolderById('id')` cannot be used for the shared Drive, please check the following modified script.

  ```
    function moveFiles2() {
      var dfldrs = ['ARCHIVE_DRW', 'ARCHIVE_BOM', 'ARCHIVE_STP'];
      var ofObj = { ARCHIVE_DRW: 'id', ARCHIVE_BOM: 'id', ARCHIVE_STP: 'id' };

      var { items } = Drive.Files.list({ q: `'id' in parents and trashed=false`, fields: "items(title,id)", maxResults: 1000, corpora: "allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true });
      items.forEach(({ id, title }) => {
        var key = title.slice(0, 11);
        var index = dfldrs.indexOf(key);
        if (index > -1) {
          Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": ofObj[key] }] }, id, null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
          // or Drive.Files.patch({ "parents": [{ "id": ofObj[key] }] }, id, { supportsAllDrives: true })
        }
      });
    }
  ```

  - In this case, it supposes that the number of files is less than 1000. If it is more than 1000, please use `pageToken` for retrieving all files.
- As another modification, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      Drive.Files.update({ "parents": [{ "id": ofObj[key] }] }, file.getId());
    ```
  - To

    ```
      file.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(ofObj[key]));
    ```

#### References:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: Can this be modified so that it can look in multiple folders? so instead of just specifying just one folder 'id' you can specify multiple?

var { items } = Drive.Files.list({ q: `'id' in parents and trashed=false`, fields: "items(title,id)", maxResults: 1000, corpora: "allDrives", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true });

Comment: @Sam.Palf About your new question of `Can this be modified so that it can look in multiple folders? so instead of just specifying just one folder 'id' you can specify multiple?`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new question, for example, how about using the search query like `('id1' in parents or 'id2' in parents ,,,) and trashed=false`? But, if I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: @Sam.Palf About `That worked great thanks!`, thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your new question was resolved. Thank you, too.